# preg_replace issue with delete everything inside parenthesis

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Inside a string I'm trying with preg_replace to remove everything inside parenthesis.

My code is:

```
$text = 'i am (really) tired';
$text = preg_replace('#\([A-Z0-9]\)#', '', $text);
echo $text;
```

but the output is:

i am (really) tired

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  turn on the case insensitive mode by adding the modifier `i` to your pattern `(?i)` or just after to the regex delimiter. And also you have to add `+` after `[A-Z0-9]` to match one or more alphanumeric characters,

```
$text = 'i am (really) tired';
$text = preg_replace('#\([A-Z0-9]+\)#i', '', $text);
echo $text;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  #\([A-Z0-9a-z]+\)#
```

Should be this.i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Without quantifier (`*`, `+`, or `{m,n}`) it only match a single character. In addition to that, `[A-Z]` match only uppercase alphabet. You need to specify `[a-z]` too. (or specify `i` flag to ignore case)

```
$text = preg_replace('#\([A-Za-z0-9]+\)#', '', $text);
```